# Return key does not work in viper-mode inside minibuffer

Tags: macos, emacs, viper-mode, viper, emacs24

My MacBook has two enter keys.

1. One is return
2. Other is enter key placed right beside command key on right hand side.

I have recently started using Emacs24. I have noticed, whenever I am in viper-mode and I issue any command, for example

```
M-x toggle-viper-mode
```

Return key does not work. Instead I get an error.

```
Wrong type argument: characterp, return
```

I have to use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> or the <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If I disable viper-mode <kbd>return</kbd> works without any error.

I tried using a solution from [Gnu Emacs mailing list archive](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2003-01/msg00546.html) but it didn't work.

```
(define-key function-key-map [return] [?\C-m])
```

How can I fix it so that return key works with commands in viper-mode too?

**Update**

The result of C-h k for return key when viper-mode is not loaded.

```
<return> runs the command autopair-newline, which is an interactive Lisp function in `autopair.el'.
It is bound to RET, <return>.
```

The result of C-h k for enter key when viper-mode is not loaded.

```
RET (translated from <kp-enter>) runs the command autopair-newline, which is an interactive Lisp function in `autopair.el'.
It is bound to RET, <return>
```

The result of C-h k for return key when viper-mode is loaded.

```
<return> runs the command autopair-newline, which is an interactive Lisp function in `autopair.el'.
It is bound to RET, <return>.
```

The result of C-h k for enter key when viper-mode is loaded.

```
RET (translated from <kp-enter>) runs the command autopair-newline, which is an interactive Lisp function in `autopair.el'.
It is bound to RET, <return>.
```

The problem is return key does not work in minibuffer when viper-mode is loaded, although the mappings are similar as you can see above.

Comment: Use `C-h k` then `return` to see what Emacs thinks the key is and what it should be doing. Compare the results with and without `viper-mode` enabled, and maybe paste your findings here.

Comment: @sanityinc I have used C-h k and added the result to my question. I didn't find anything useful. The return key map does not change in viper-mode.

Comment: So logically `autopair-newline` is not working correctly in `viper-mode`, right? The source for that function indicates is has some special handling of the "RET" keyboard binding.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Thanks. I have moved to evil now. It does not give me any problem.

Comment: Great, if that helped then I'll paste my feedback as an answer so you can maybe accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that `autopair-newline` is not working correctly in viper-mode. The source for that function indicates is has some special handling of the "RET" keyboard binding.